# ASP.NET Core - Entity Framework Core: Access relationship when posting a typed form

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am posting a form in ASP.NET Core. I have an HTML element that shows a list of colors. The values of the select's options are mapped to ids in the color table. The problem is that I want to access the name of color in the back-end but I am getting a null reference. How can I remedy this in a good way?

```
Model  
Carro
{
        [Column("id_color")]
        public int IdColor { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("IdColor")]
        public Color Color { get; set;}
}


[Table("color")]
    public class Color
    {
        [Key]
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("color_name")]
        public string ColorName{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

My select html element is using a typed Car form.

@model Car

```
         <form asp-route="store_car" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <div>
                <label>Cor</label>
                <select asp-for="IdColor" class="form-control" id="selectCoresCarro"></select>

            </div>
```

My Action

```
  [HttpPost]
    [Route("/carros/anunciar", Name = "store_car")]

        public IActionResult CadastrarCarro(Car car){

      car.Color.ColorName; // Color is undefined. 

 }
```

Can someone give a good solution for this. I didn't want to write code to query the database.

Comment: If you update the form to the following <select asp-for="Carro.IdColor" it should apply to the child object. Looking at this solution I would have had the colours as Enums in your application code. Then you could use the select list on the enums.

Comment: @eVolve what you are saying makes sense. I am using PostgreSQL and it has Enums as data types. I have already seem people use PostgreSQL enums in C# (and vice-versa). I can check this later on, now I am just prototyping my app, so I am hoping for a solution that works magically, even if the solution is not one that uses the best techniques. If I just create Enums it will be fine for small tables, but I have similar problem with model ids that have thousands of records.

Comment: A workaround is add hidden field to your page and bind the Color.ColorName , and in  form post will send the hidden field to controller side .